# If I implement google calendar API, will my users need a gmail account?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-calendar-api

I am looking for a good Calendar API for my app, and google calendar seems like a good fit. However, I am worried that my users will not be able to use my embedded calendar without a gmail account

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partially correct. Users won't be able to use Google Calendar without a **Google Account**. Users can have a Google account without having a **Gmail account**. Those types of accounts are called **non-Gmail Google accounts**. To register for one of those accounts you need to follow the instructions explained here https://www.steadydemand.com/how-to-setup-a-google-plus-account-with-you-company-domain-name/. Users will then have access to google services, like contacts, calendar, drive but not Gmail.